# Ошибка в скрипте? на safari и ie - display: none не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, safari, display

Не могу скрыть в указанных браузерах один параграф. 
Мне нужно убрать предложение о бесплатном звонке именно из safari и ie, т.к. виджет "Позвонить с сайта бесплатно" в этих браузерах не работает.

С помощью одного из участников этого форума у меня теперь есть скрипт, которым я получаю данные о браузере пользователя. И в зависимости от браузера подгружаю соответствующие стили.

```js
function get_name_browser(){
    // получаем данные userAgent
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
    // с помощью регулярного выражения
    // ищем упоминание названия браузера
    if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return false;
    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return  false;
    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return  false;
    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';
    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'IE';
    if (ua.search(/msedge/) > 0) return 'IE';
    return false;
}


// сравниваем название и подключаем нужный css

if (get_name_browser() == "Safari") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="safari.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() == "IE") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="IE.css">');
}
```

```css
@media (max-width : 800px)
{ 
    .show-on-mobile { display: inline; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: none; }
    .except-ie-safari { display: none;}
}
 
@media (min-width: 801px)   
{   
    .show-on-mobile { display: none; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: inline; }
    .except-ie-safari { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<p class="except-ie-safari" style="text-align: center;"> бесплатным
            звонком с сайта </p>
```

Но в ie и safari **p class="except-ie-safari"** не убирается.

display: none не срабатывает в этих браузерах.

Как победить?
Спасибо.

Пробовала еще так:

```js
if (get_name_browser() === "Safari" || get_name_browser() === "IE") {
  document.getElementByClass("except-ie-safari").classList.add("hide-ie-safari");
}
```

```css
.except-ie-safari.hide-ie-safari { display: none; }
```

```html
<p class="except-ie-safari" style="text-align: center;"> бесплатным звонком с сайта </p>
```

Но, видимо, что-то напутала. Я js не владею, к сожалению.

Пробовала индекс добавлять:
...

```js
[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Пробовала класс добавлять (по совету из комментариев):

```js
if (get_name_browser() === "Safari" || get_name_browser() === "IE") {
  document.getElementsByClassName("except-ie-safari").classList.add("hide-ie-safari");
}
```

Результат нулевой

Comment: Если определяется ie или safari, то просто добавлять элементу который нужно скрыть `display: none`. Зачем тянуть css?

Comment: Я именно это и пытаюсь сделать. Но я владею только html и css. Поэтому очень желательно решить задачу с их помощью.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("except-ie-safari")[0].classList...`

Comment: @Наталья Вот Вы пишете код `document.getElementByClass(...`. При этом в голове мысль: "Я js не владею." Почему бы не набрать в поиске - "document.getElementByClass" и не посмотреть, как этой функцией пользоваться, и существует ли она?

Comment: Потому что мне это ничего не даст. Вы мыслите как программист, а я как верстальщик. Я смотрела выдачу поисковиков по этому запросу и пыталась применить к своей ситуации. Моя задача не решена, к сожалению. getElementsByClassName() - опечаталась

Comment: А метод .classList я еще неделю разбирать буду :(

Comment: Не работает у меня  document.getElementByClassName(название класса).classList.add (название класса);  -также, как все остальное :(((

Comment: @Наталья Вы внимательно читаете реплики собеседника? У `document` нет метода `getElementByClassName`, но есть метод `getElementsByClassName`. Одна буковка - какая ерунда!

Comment: Игорь, я и так и эдак пробовала https://www.baseflat.ru/myiesafari.js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85222/discussion-between--and-igor).

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем скрипте было несколько синтаксических ошибок. В таких случаях полезно открыть консоль браузера и посмотреть там сообщения об ошибках.

Не знаю, где Вы взяли скрипт для определения браузера, но у меня ни Edge, ни IE, ни Opera им не определяются.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

```js
function get_name_browser() {
  // �������� ������ userAgent
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  // � ������� ����������� ���������
  // ���� ���������� �������� ��������
  if (ua.search(/chrome/i) > 0) return 'Chrome';
  if (ua.search(/firefox/i) > 0) return 'Firefox';
  if (ua.search(/opera/i) > 0) return 'Opera';
  if (ua.search(/safari/i) > 0) return 'Safari';
  if (ua.search(/MSIE/i) > 0) return 'IE';
  if (ua.search(/msedge/i) > 0) return 'IE';

  return 'unknown';
}

// ���������� �������� � ���������� ������ css

if (get_name_browser() === "Safari") {
  console.log("adding Safari css");
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="safari.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() === "IE") {
  console.log("adding IE css");
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="IE.css">');
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log(navigator.userAgent);
  console.log(get_name_browser());

  var excepts = document.getElementsByClassName('except-' + get_name_browser().toLowerCase());
  for (var i = 0; i < excepts.length; i++) {
    //excepts[i].style.display = 'none'; // !!! uncomment this line
    excepts[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
});
```

```css
.ua {
  background: lightGreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ua except-chrome">Chrome</div>
<div class="ua except-firefox">Firefox</div>
<div class="ua except-opera">Opera</div>
<div class="ua except-safari">Safari</div>
<div class="ua except-ie">IE</div>
<div class="ua except-safari except-ie">Safari & IE</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Скрипт предложили здесь же в другой ветке. А консоль - отличная вещь. Только непонятная мне пока. Впрочем, я уже вдохновилась js выучить :) Так что близкое знакомство с консолью мне гарантировано в ближайшее время.Завтра попробую код, предложенный Вами и напишу, что у меня получилось

Answer (score 0):

Если определяется ie или safari, то просто добавлять элементу который нужно скрыть display: none. Зачем тянуть css?

```
if (get_name_browser() === "Safari" || get_name_browser() === "IE") {
  document.getElementById('paragraph').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Попробовала, не сработало. Может быть потому, что Вы предлагаете использовать getElementById, а у меня класс элементу присвоен, а не id?

Comment: Попыталась написать так: if (get_name_browser() === "Safari" || get_name_browser() === "IE") {
  document.getElementsByClassName('except-ie-safari').style.display = "none";
}

Comment: И не работает, увы :(

Comment: @Наталья `document.querySelector('.except-ie-safari').style.display = "none";`

Comment: Не получается ничего. Здесь файл js: https://www.baseflat.ru/myiesafari.js

Comment: Здесь тестовая страница в html: https://www.baseflat.ru/dlit-telwidtool-finish-menu-2-autoprefixer-clicktel-3.html .   Параграф, который нужно удалить из IE и Safari в коде - на 240 строке.  Что неправильно делаю?